# Is Node JS needed to build Angular JS app ? If yes why? Why don't we need node js in production env?

Tags: angularjs

Is Node JS needed to build Angular JS app ? If yes why?

I read some articles theh say you need Node JS to build angular js app but it is not needed in production. I don't understand why?
Even in my project I start Node JS server and then run UI, but we don't do that in production ?

Answer (score 0):

Q1: **Is Node JS needed to build Angular JS app?**

- No, NodeJS is server side and Angular JS is client.
- NodeJS is server side environment which enables javascript to run server side
- You could use e.g. PHP or C#(ASP.NET) or Java server side (any server programming language) and use AngularJS client side.

Q2: **Why don't we need node js in production env?**

- Not sure what you are trying to ask here. But if you are using some other server programming language, you do not need nodeJS but if you are using Javascript server side, you'd need it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need node to create an AngularJS app, although it is helpful for spinning up a quick server, installing dependencies, etc.

I am wondering if you are actually referring to Angular (2+) and not AngularJS. Although node is still not required, I would think it would be highly recommended in order to make use of the [CLI](https://cli.angular.io/). I definitely wouldn't recommend doing Angular development without node.

Also - just to clarify, what we upload to production often isn't what we have on our development machine. On most of my projects no matter if it is Angular or not, I'll use some kind of task runner to run certain tasks (jshint, unit tests, end to end tests, minify, etc). Those things aren't needed in production. In fact, usually the code we write doesn't get uploaded directly - it goes through a bunch of transpiling, minification, concatenation, etc. before it gets put into a dist folder and uploaded to a server.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant build as the activity that includes the steps before your app ships to the browser, then yes, you need server side (node.js) tasks to minify, uglify, generate source maps etc. If you don't need to build your app, AngularJS can be used without the support of node.js libs.
Normally, in development you would use a local development server to not need an Apache server. That blog you mention it, maybe said that you don't need node.js after you code is built, because is already ready to use in production without the need of node.js libraries like the local development server.

In production, you app has only client code that was created using AngularJS and was built by node.js libs before it ships to client browser, in that sense, the final app that goes to the browser doesn't contain node.js code.